# CSP: frame-src violation with empty blocked-uri

Tags: content-security-policy

Sometimes I observe CSP violations for frame-src in the collected reports which have an empty blocked-uri attribute. The user agent indicates that the violations was triggered within Chrome 75 on Windows 10.

The policy mainly looks like **default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ; frame-src https:**

I didn't succeed in reproducing this type of violation, nor is there any complaint about a blocked/missing feature.
Any idea what could be the reason for these violations?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit: Such violations are triggered when the framed page internally navigates to a domain which is not allowed by the parent's policy. For security reasons it's OK to leave the blocked-URI field empty in this case as otherwise the target domain would be disclosed to the owner of the framing page.